# Could not find method sonarProperties()

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

I'm trying to configure `build.gradle` for generating and uploading code coverage report to sonar

```
import static org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os.*

buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.1"
  }
}

 plugins {
   id "org.sonarqube" version "2.6.1"
   id "java" 
 }

task sonarRunner {
        sonarProperties {
                property "sonar.host.url", sonar.host.url
                property "sonar.organization", sonar.organization
                property "sonar.projectKey", sonar.projectKey
                property "sonar.login", sonar.login
                property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", sonar.jacoco.reportPath
        }
}

task generateReport {
        exec {
          commandLine 'ant', 'jacoccoalltests', '-Dtestclasses.extensions=' + code.coverage.extensions
      }

}

task checkOs() << {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine 'setantenv.bat'
    }
    if(Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_UNIX)) {
        exec {
          executable "./setantenv.sh"
        }
    }
    if(Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_MAC)) {
        exec {
          executable ". ./setantenv.sh"
        }
    }
}

sonarRunner.dependsOn generateReport
generateReport.dependsOn checkOs
```

When I run **./gradlew clean build** I have the following error

> Caused by:
>   org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException:
>   Could not find method sonarProperties() for arguments
>   [build_5g79eps6d8kumu5fvgq9l0s46$_run_closure1$_closure5@1f58d70] on
>   task ':sonarRunner' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: this is not how `sonarqube` plugin must be configured: for setting sonar properties you need to configure the `sonarqube` extension, which exposes a `properties` extension. See : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforGradle-Passingmanualproperties/overridingdefaults

Comment: `sonarRunner` is not a task, remove the keywork and keep it as a block `sonarRunner { sonarProperties { ...`

Answer (score 0):

In order to configure the *SonarQube* plugin, you need to use the *Gradle extension* named `sonarqube`, as described [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforGradle-Passingmanualproperties/overridingdefaults)

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.exclusions", "**/*Generated.java"
        property "sonar.host.url", sonar.host.url
        property "sonar.organization", sonar.organization
        property "sonar.projectKey", sonar.projectKey
        property "sonar.login", sonar.login
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", sonar.jacoco.reportPath     
    }
}
```

See also README from this plugin repo [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-gradle)